# Android, trying to call a new intent from a touch event

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a app that when the screen is touch it will call up a new intent.
I have code that catches the touch event in the view class.  When I try to create a new intent, Intent(this, cYesNoDisplay.class);, i get a error saying the constuctor is undefined, I'm assuming the constructor is not defined in the view base class, but the Activity class?

I'm confused about how to do this, is there a way for my View class that is a member of the intent class, to call it some how????  I figure there must be a wy to do this, still learning Java.
Ted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assesment about the View class that you are inside of being the problem is correct. In order to get it working do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(NameOfYourActivity.this, cYesNoDisplay.class);
```

replace [NameOfYourActivity] with the name of the activity that you are inside of.

**EDIT:** I might have misunderstood what you were doing. If you have actually built your own View class and are overriding onTouch() you actually need to do it a little bit differently.

If you don't already have it add:

```
Context ctx;
```

to your classes declarations.

in your constructor alter it to store the context that gets passed in as a parameter in the ctx reference that you declared.

```
public [ClassName] (Context c){
    this.ctx = c;
}
```

Then inside the onTouch() do it like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, cYesNoDisplay.class);
ctx.startActivity();
```

**EDIT again:** The reason you have to use `ctx.startActivity(i);` is that startActivity() is a method of Context. Since Activity *is a*  Context you don't have to put anything in front of it when you call it from inside an activity. But when you are "inside" of a different class you have to use a reference to a Context to call the method.

Comment: thank you for your help, but i still cannot get it to work. Your code compiles fine Intent i = new Intent(ctx, cYesNoDisplay.class); i added the following line to start the intent startActivity(i); .  This gives me a compile error saying the method does not exist. -Ted

Comment: sorry you'll need to do ctx.startActivity(i); I added that as an Edit in my answer just now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this . this work fine in my project.

Intent i = new Intent(NameOfYourActivity.this, cYesNoDisplay.class);
startActivity(i);